# Weighted average

Tags: operational-amplifier, pid-controller, math

I'm kinda new to this forum. I'm an electronics student from Argentina (sorry if my English is not the best, you know). I'm a robotics enthusiast. Now I'm building a racing robot.
The thing is: it's a line follower that uses [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) with a weighted average of the sensors' values, to know "where the robot is" having the line as the reference. For the ones who don't know, weighted average is

(v1*w1)+(v2*w2)+...(vn*wn)/(w1+w2+...wn)

(v = value, w = weight)

I use a number from 1 to N (quantity of sensors) as the value and the voltage as the weight. In this way I can know where, within the sensor array, the darkness is concentrated. 
A friend gave me the idea to calculate the weighted average with op-amps, because I can save time and processing and make it more precise (analog > digital). I've been doing some research and found that I could use resistors to give weight to the voltages. But I couldn't really understand because I've just started learning op-amps and I know almost nothing about them. Could you tell me how to achieve this? Or at least how to make operations such as sum, product and division...

Sorry for the long text and thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you looking for a single analog output to give a left, right, no turn type indication? The greater the absolute value, the more correction is needed? What type of sensors will you be using?

Comment: @GlennW9IQ think it as if I had to average N analog voltages within 0v-VCC (5v in this case) range. Anyway, I'm using CNY70 sensors, that give voltages proportional to the darker they "see". I've done this before but all inside the processor I was using (Arduino/PIC). I know the formula is the right one, I just want to make it with op-amps, or some external component.

Comment: inverting op amp gain is controlled by individual series R and shared feedback R so it is simple, IF you know and include the source impedance

Comment: The CNY70 only has a 1cm range with inverted squared relationship , so Ideally you use a log amp and stagger them to increase the range. Also black must be high carbon and not any old black for high SNR for contrast with IR . check paint and compare with a Black Sharpy or laser test coupon . thus your assumption of linear weighting is flawed with gap variations (road bumps) from inverse square law.  A more linear long range design uses modulated carrier like TV remotes with AGC and stepped pulses

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 yeah yeah, they've always worked for me, that's not a problem

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 could you send me a schematic circuit or something?

Comment: We used to count RPM of hydro power electric disk with our own custom IR emitter detector with aperture and angle to focus on surface , which performs far better than the CNY70

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 but it's good for me... Just national academic robotics lol

Comment: we would have to use mental telepathy   I did this over 20 yrs ago

Comment: the measure of a good servo is the integrated error squared or rather the integral of the squared error but for HDD servo it is just position error squared.. watch out for blind spots from irregular surfaces that may look,black

Comment: what is your gap? and 3 sigma and expected SNR?? worst case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic summing circuit using an op-amp is shown below.

[image: Image source Wikipedia]

(Image credit to Wikipedia)

The transfer function is V<sub>out</sub>=-R<sub>f</sub>*V<sub>n</sub>/R<sub>n</sub> for each input. The value of input V<sub>n</sub> can therefore be weighted through the selection of R<sub>n</sub>. The sum of all inputs must not exceed the maximum V<sub>out</sub> of the op-amp.

While it is possible to build a summing amplifier in a non-inverting format, the number of practical inputs is can be significantly limited. So generally the inverting form shown is applied and if necessary, a second unity gain inverting op-amp follows it to provide an overall positive summing function.

Strictly speaking an averaging function is not necessary in your application since the number of inputs is fixed so a simple scaling function is all that is required. Of course the scaling function can be selected to obtain an average. The scaling can be done through the selection of R<sub>f</sub> and R<sub>n</sub> or it can be performed through a simple resistive divider on the output of the op-amp. If the divider is placed between the two inverting op amps, the gain of the second op amp could then be used to scale the result to the input range of a A/D converter, for example.

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted, because I want Vn to be the weight and N the value (can also be scaled, e.g: N*100). In that case I'd be dividing by Rf, that (what I understood) would be the sum of all R's... Sorry if I didn't explain well, but thanks anyway

Comment: In your formula above, V and W are interchangeable in each term, so simply consider the -Rf/Rn as the W factor.

Comment: oooooh now I understand. I thought that you were wrong. Thankssss, I'll try that

Comment: What do you mean when saying "The sum of all inputs must not exceed the maximum Vout of the op-amp"? Max Vout = VCC+?

Comment: Max Vout is < Vcc